# Kotlin: open new Activity inside of a Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-intent

How can I open a new Activity inside of a fragment when using a button?

I tried this

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    LogOut_btn.setOnClickListener {
        //FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
        val intent = Intent (this, Main::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)            
    }
}
```

> val intent = Intent doesn't seem to work in a fragment.

Any idea how I can start a new activity inside a fragment?

Comment: `getActivity().startActivity(intent)`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Because `Fragment` is NOT of `Context` type, you'll need to call the parent `Activity`:

```
 val intent = Intent (getActivity(), Main::class.java)
 getActivity().startActivity(intent)
```

or maybe something like

```
activity?.let{
    val intent = Intent (it, Main::class.java)
    it.startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but the app still crashes when I open the activity where the fragment is shown starts

Comment: What's the exception you're getting? maybe you forgot to declare the activity in the manifest?

Comment: I am the dumbest person in the universe. I have 3 fragments and all the time I wrote in the wrong one. Really sorry for my stupidity. Thank you for helping me

Comment: nah. you're just another person in the universe. 

Comment: It does not work for me. Could it be because my fragment is not a button?

Answer (score 6):

You can do smth like this in kotlin

```
YourButton.setOnClickListener{
            requireActivity().run{
                startActivity(Intent(this, NeededActivity::class.java))
                finish()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only use `activity` returns just an Activity instance. This can be any activity that embeds your fragment so in some cases you can get FragmentActivity instead your parent activity. Use this to make sure you are getting the correct one:

```
(activity as? YourParentActivity)?.let{
    val intent = Intent (it, Main::class.java)
    it.startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: You need to move the `?` or this will cause a cast exception when this Fragment is attached to something other than `YourParentActivity.` Use `(activity as? YourParentActivity)`. And of course we only need to cast at all if we need to call a function that is a specific method of YourParentActivity.

Comment: You are totally right @Tenfour04. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 4):

```
val intent = Intent (getActivity(), NextActivity::class.java)
getActivity()?.startActivity(intent)
```

This will do the job.

getActivity() as it's casted from a Fragment and getActivity()? to avoid NPE

Hope it helps :)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Богдан Опир not helpful tbh.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it would be something like

```
activity?.let { callingActivity -> startActivity(Intent(callingActivity, Main::class.java)) }
```

You must use the calling activities `context`

Comment: Thank you for your effort but the app still crashes

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost done, you just need to pass the fragment instance as the first parameter of Intent replace **YourFragmentName** with your fragment name after the @, bellow:

```
val intent = Intent (this@YourFragmentName.context, Main::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Look at this sample bellow:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment(){

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        val intent = Intent (this@MyFragment.context, YOUR_NEXT_ACTIVITY_CLASS::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all I want to thank you for trying to help me, but when I put my fragments name in there the Intent stops working and gets a red underline.

Comment: sorry its still crashing. Should I even ride this in override fun onViewCreated or in something else. Maybe I shouldn't do that with a fragment

Comment: I added another sample

Comment: Why is it class.java for your next activity class? I thought we written this using kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

For me i just did this and it worked

```
val intent = Intent(AppName.applicationContext(), YourAppName::class.java)
activity?.startActivity(intent)
```

You can add this code into your fragment

```
AppName
```

This is the Application name which holds global companion object like `context`

Answer (score 1):

Also an option (for kotlin).
In onCreateView set onClickListener for a button:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    requireActivity().run {
        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
        finish() // If activity no more needed in back stack
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this

```
LogOut_btn.setOnClickListener {
        //FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
         val intent = Intent (this, Main::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)



    }
```

inside the onCreate method of the Activity where the fragment is loaded

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the context from the fragment instead

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

  LogOut_btn.setOnClickListener {
    //FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
     val intent = Intent (view.context, Main::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut() before the intent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I found while trying to get something similar to work.

```
view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_second).setOnClickListener {
  val i = Intent(activity, ClassNameOfActivityIWantToGoTo::class.java)
  activity?.startActivity(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val  intent = Intent(activity, AttachmentActivity::class.java)
            activity!!.startActivity(intent)
             activity!!.finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 val intent = Intent (getActivity(), Main::class.java)
 getActivity().startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28329088)

Answer (score -1):

```
 override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
```

val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YourFragmentLayout, container, false)

```
    view.button.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(requireContext(), YourActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }


    return view
```

}