# How To Move Activity Form Fragment "Kotlin"

Tags: android, kotlin

How do you move the Activity from the Fragment? using Kotlin

```
btnGlobal.setOnClickListener {  
  val intent = Intent (getActivity(), Main2Activity::class.java)
  getActivity()?.startActivity(intent)
}`
```

Comment: You mean open activity from fragment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin: open new Activity inside of a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355786/kotlin-open-new-activity-inside-of-a-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are willing to go to another activity named `Main2Activity` from your current activity. If it is then the process is as follows:

```
btnGlobal.setOnClickListener {  
    val intent = Intent (requireActivity(), Main2Activity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    // For finishing current activity use below line
    // requireActivity().finish()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a fragment do the following:

```
btnGlobal.setOnClickListener {  
  val intent = Intent (activity!!, Main2Activity::class.java)
  startActivity(intent)
}
```

If you are on an Activity do the following:

```
btnGlobal.setOnClickListener {  
  val intent = Intent (TheNameOfThisActivity@this, Main2Activity::class.java)
  startActivity(intent)
}
```