# How to move from an activity to a fragment in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a fragment and when clicking on a button I move to an activity ,and while back pressed from that activity I want to move back to that fragment ? How to do that in kotlin

I need to move from an activity to a fragment

Answer (score 0):

You need context in order to move from **Fragment** to **Activity**. For that you can get context from **Fragment's** parent activity and then open another activity.

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355786/kotlin-open-new-activity-inside-of-a-fragment) thread to get better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Navigation Component library for better navigation between screens.